# Outlook Interop: is there a way to check if an Outlook folder is read-only

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I'm writing a piece of code in C# to get all writable Calendars from Outlook via Outlook Interop. The calendars in Outlook are just Outlook folders whose default item type is `OlItemType.olAppointmentItem`. However, there are always read-only Calendars such as the Birthday Calendar if you add your Hotmail account to Outlook.

Is there a way to detect these read-only Calendars?

Comment: The general answer for anything that lives on the file system like is to actually try to write to it, and then handle the exception if it fails. Otherwise, you're just creating a race condition.

Comment: This is the only way I can think of for now too. I've been using the following code to check it but I'm not sure if there's a better way: `((AppointmentItem)folder.Items.Add(OlItemType.olAppointmentItem)).Delete()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like there's no dedicated method to check if the current user has permission to write to an outlook folder provided that it might not be an exchange folder. Therefore the most reliable way is probably try creating and deleting a dummy item:

```
try
{
    ((AppointmentItem)calendarFolder.Items.Add(OlItemType.olAppointmentItem)).Delete();

    // Do whatever you need with this folder.
}
catch
{
    // This probably means the folder is not writeable.
}
```

Note that the item type needs to match the folder default item type.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this somewhat easily if these were exchange accounts but you specifically mentioned hotmail so it appears, after much research, the only way to do this is by using a third party plugin or writing your own wrapper around the MAPI/ACL library. Microsoft never made the ACLs available through the com namespace.

Everyone is suggesting Redemption: http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/home.htm, you can check out the RDOACL functionality they expose here:

http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOACL.htm